# Materialize form input not to change color on click

Tags: css, materialize

I've just started to use materialize and here is my biggest problem.
    When i click on the input the color of the label is changing in blue. 
    The thing is that i want to be still green. What can i do?
    Photos below:

Normal view

[image]

On click view

[image]

After you write view + Css

[image]

Thank you, Mihai!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your CSS? Have you looked at how you can override CSS for selected elements?

Comment: The thing is that i can't find the part where it change the color ( it's custom css from materialize with thousand of ugly code ). I found only the transition, the part when you click on input becomes bigger, but nothing about color.

Comment: Look for the Css selector :focus. This is really basic Css, and IMPOSSIBLE for us to answer without any code. I would recommend you look at introduction tutorials for CSS before trying to solve something beyond your skill level. The images shared here are of no technical use.

Comment: I was looking for the css selector :focus and find the problem. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can just simpy change your css

```
.input-field input[type=text]:focus + label {
 color: YOUR_GREEN_COLOR;
}

/* label underline focus color */
.input-field input[type=text]:focus {
 border-bottom: 1px solid YOUR_GREEN_COLOR;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 YOUR_GREEN_COLOR;
}
```